# Using Parallel.ForEach for insert and update CRM data

Tags: c#, for-loop, parallel-processing, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I need to update CRM data from external table. All working fine but its very slow. This is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
var dbClient = new CollectionEntities(); //Get database Entities
using(var xrm = new XrmServiceContext("Xrm"); // Get CRM Entities
    {
foreach (var row in dbClient.Client) //Reading rows from database
{
var c = (from a in crm.new_clientSet where a.new_Idnumber == row.Client_ID select a).FirstOrDefault(); // IS there clint with id from database
                            if (c == null)// if client not exist i create new if exists I update data
                            {
                                c = new new_client { new_Idnumber = row.Client_ID };
                                crm.AddObject(c);
                            }
                            c.new_name = row.Client_name; //[Client_name]
                            c.new_Idnumber = row.Client_ID;//[Client_ID]
                            c.EmailAddress = row.Email;//[Email]
                xrm.AddObject(c);
                    xrm.SaveChanges();

}
}
}
```

With this I can insert and update data in CRM but its to slow. Is there a way to use for this Parallel.ForEach method or some other method to speed up this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely [ExecuteMultipleRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.executemultiplerequest(v=crm.7).aspx) is the way to go in that case.

The difference is that you'll send a single request so you won't have the network overhead and also, all your inserts will be processed on server-side by CRM, much quicker.

Answer (score 1):

You are loading a single row from CRM inside every loop. This makes your app very "chatty" and it is spending more time in network overhead than loading data. Try to load your entire CRM dataset into memory with a single query before the loop. Then, in the loop, lookup records from memory instead of querying CRM. You will probably need to use paging cookies if you have a large dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the open source [PFE Core Library for Dynamics CRM](https://pfexrmcore.codeplex.com/documentation) library from the Premier Field Engineering - Dynamics team at Microsoft.  It handles parallelism for you.  The [Parallel Common Request](https://pfexrmcore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Microsoft.Pfe.Xrm.Core.Samples/ParallelRequestSamples.cs) examples page shows how easy it is to update a bunch of records in parallel:

```
public void ParallelUpdate(List<Entity> targets)
{
    try
    {
        this.Manager.ParallelProxy.Update(targets);
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        // Handle exceptions
    }
}
```

You can also use it to query for large data sets...it will handle retrieving everything for you.